# How to prove that $\;n\log(n) = O(\log(n!))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-science

How can I start from $\;n\log(n)\;$ and show that $\;n\log n\leqslant c\cdot\log(n!)\;$ for $\;c>0\;.$

I understand how to show that $\;n\log(n!)>\dfrac n2\cdot\log\left(\dfrac n2\right)\;.$

How can I continue from there?

Comment: Can you show $\frac{n \log n}{\log(n!)}$ is monotonically decreasing?  (It's decreasing on $(0, \infty)$, but it's enough to find an $N$ such that it's monotonically decreasing on $(N, \infty)$.)

Comment: Why thats helps ? How its show $nlog(n) <= c * log(n!)?$

Comment: Suppose $\frac{n \log n}{\log(n!)}$ is positive and monotonically decreasing on $(N,\infty)$ and also $\frac{N \log N}{\log(N!)} = c$.  Then for $n \geq N$, $\frac{n \log n}{\log(n!)} \leq c$.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to start from $\log n!=\log1+\log2+\cdots+\log n$,

Using Gauss' schoolboy trick for summing $1+2+\cdots+n$ we can say

$$ 2\log n!=\log(1\cdot n)+\log(2\cdot (n-1))+\cdots+\log(n\cdot1). $$

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 2):

$\ln(n!)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln(k)\leq n\ln n$. On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=2}^{n}\ln k & \geq & \sum_{k=2}^{n}\int_{k-1}^{k}\ln x\,dx\\
 & = & \int_{1}^{n}\ln x\,dx\\
 & = & \left[x\ln x\right]_{1}^{n}-\int_{1}^{n}dx\\
 & = & n\ln n-(n-1).
\end{eqnarray*}
For $n\geq e^{4}$, $n\ln n\geq n\cdot\ln e^{4}=4n$. Hence, $n\ln n-(n-1)\geq\frac{1}{2}n\ln n+\frac{1}{2}\cdot4n-(n-1)\geq\frac{1}{2}n\ln n$.

We conclude that, for $n\geq e^{4},$
$$
\frac{1}{2}n\ln n\leq\ln(n!)\leq n\ln n.
$$
It follows that $n\ln n\sim O(\ln(n!))$.

Remark: Actually, we can do more. Clearly, $\frac{\ln(n!)}{n\ln n}\leq1$
and $\frac{\ln(n!)}{n\ln n}\geq\frac{n\ln n-(n-1)}{n\ln n}=1-\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{\ln n}\rightarrow1$
as $n\rightarrow\infty$. By sandwich rule, we have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln(n!)}{n\ln n}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle\;\log\big(n!\big)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log k\leqslant\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log n=n\log n\;.$

Moreover,

$\displaystyle n\log n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log n\leqslant\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log\big[(n-k)(k-1)+n\big]=$

$\displaystyle=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log\big(kn-k^2+k\big)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log\big[k(n-k+1)\big]=$

$\displaystyle=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log k+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log\big(n-k+1\big)=$

$\displaystyle=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log k+\sum\limits_{h=1}^n\log h=2\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\log k=$

$\displaystyle=2\log\big(n!\big)\;.$

Hence, it results that

$\log\big(n!\big)\leqslant n\log n\leqslant 2\log\big(n!\big)\;.$